# Yii2 freezes when including Yii.php in config

Tags: php, yii2

I just migrated over to a new server and now when I try to access my application it will never load. I'm not getting any errors in the error log the page just sits in an infinite load.

I have been trying to figure this out all night but can't find any reason, I've checked that I copied over all the files. Any ideas where I might be missing something.

I found that if I uncomment the Yii.php line it will load a blank page.

Here is my index file

```
require(__DIR__ . '/../../vendor/autoload.php');
require(__DIR__ . '/../../vendor/yiisoft/yii2/Yii.php');
require(__DIR__ . '/../../common/config/bootstrap.php');
require(__DIR__ . '/../config/bootstrap.php');

$config = yii\helpers\ArrayHelper::merge(
    require(__DIR__ . '/../../common/config/main.php'),
    require(__DIR__ . '/../../common/config/main-local.php'),
    require(__DIR__ . '/../config/main.php'),
    require(__DIR__ . '/../config/main-local.php')
);

$application = new yii\web\Application($config);
$application->run();
```

Comment: Any errors you getting in your `error.log` file?

Comment: no because the page never even finishes loading

Comment: Search for a error log for your apache server, because there should some errors

Comment: I checked again and there are no errors for this, the problem is that the page seems to go into an infinite loop and never actually loads. Also when I load this site, it makes me have to restart apache to load other websites hosted on the same server

Comment: put these lines above all in `index.php`, might get some clue: `ini_set('display_errors', 'on'); error_reporting(E_ALL)`

Comment: nope, the server is not even returning a response to the browser, the page sits in infinite load

Answer (score 1):

Yii.php file is controlled by composer. So don't copy `vendor` folder.
Just using `composer update` command. This command will fetch new yii2 for you.

Comment: That is what I did originally and got the same error